# Show a non-monotone function is eventually positive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In general, if I have a function with limit zero, and increases from negative to positive, and then decreases to zero, how could I show there is an X so that for all $x \geq X$, $f(x) \geq 0$? Since the function is not monotone, I can't use Rolle's theorem. [image]

Comment: In your graph, it does get monotone and limited after a certain point. Maybe you can apply for $f|X$, where $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x \ge x_0\}$. Or maybe you could limit the amplitude of any oscillations that might occur as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Either it's an assumption in your description "decreases to zero" or it's wrong - take for example $f(x)=\sin(x) e^{-x^2}$. Or maybe I'm missing somthing?